# How to read .txt file and count the same elements and list them all with Python?

Tags: python, counter

I first used this method using `Terminal/Python3`.

```
>>>from collections import Counter
>>> z = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
>>> Counter(z)
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'yellow': 1})
```

However I realized that I had more than 800 elements so wanted to somehow open txt file and then proceed this measure.

Comment: Could you give the format or an example of the text file?

Comment: The text file that looks like this

A BB CC 
D DDD E G BB
GG EEE QQQ CC

Its a list of random words.

Comment: Why have you tagged the question for Rich Text Format (RTF) files? Is it actually a `.rtf` file, or is it plain text?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was RTF but realized that it was a .txt. Have untagged it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to split the text file into a list which is quite simple. An example code would look something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

f = open("test.txt")  # open file (replace "test" with file name)
z = f.read().split()  # read and split into list (default splits by spaces)
f.close()             # close file

print Counter(z)      # add parenthesis if python 3
```

Comment: Thank you! Had problem when >>>print Counter(z), what really needed was just the >>>Counter(z) though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could just store it into a variable(`variable = Counter(z)`)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the file handler:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('large-file.txt') as f:
   c = Counter(f)

print(c.most_common())
```